# how to find out Schedulable class is already scheduled or not?

Tags: soql, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I have a apex class which implements Schedulable interface, I want to find out whether this class is already scheduled or not? Please help me with SOQL query to find out this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out if a given class is scheduled use an SOQL query like:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Status, CompletedDate
    FROM AsyncApexJob
    WHERE ApexClass.NamespacePrefix = :namespace
            AND ApexClass.Name = :className
```

Where namespace is your namespace (leave out if you are not in a package) and className is the class name string, such as "MyExampleSchedulable".

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is the [Monitor Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_monitoring) trailheal module.  Gives nice SOQL queries, like:

```
AsyncApexJob jobInfo = [SELECT Status, NumberOfErrors
    FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :jobID];
```

Comment: I don't know jobID, I have only class name or Class Id with me. How do we find out this class is already scheduled in system or not?